# Calling change function at document start

Tags: jquery

I have implemented following code:

```
$('#select1').change(function() {
    var options = '';
    if($(this).val() == 'a') {
        options = '<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>';
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == 'b'){
        options = '<option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>';
    }

    $('#select2').html(options);
});
```

When the document is initialised i would like to call the change function first time, to populate my `select`, rather than changing options to trigger `change`. Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
$("#select1").trigger("change");
```

Or even shorter:

```
$("#select1").change();
```

So finally your code might look so:

```
$(function() {
    $("#select1").change(function() {
        var options = "";
        if ($(this).val() == "a") {
            options = '<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>';
        } else if ($(this).val() == "b") {
            options = '<option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>';
        }

        $("#select2").html(options);
    }).trigger("change");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the change event in the [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event.

```
$(function(){      

  $('#select1').change(function() {
     var options = '';
     if($(this).val() == 'a') {
         options = '<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>';
     } 
     else if ($(this).val() == 'b'){
         options = '<option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>';
     }
     $('#select2').html(options);
  });

  $("#select1").trigger("change");  

});
```